# Is this dct (FFTW.jl) behavior in julia normal?

Tags: julia, fft, dct

I'm trying to do some exercises of Compressed Sensing on Julia, but i realize that the discrete cosine transformation (using FFTW.jl) of an identity matrix doesn't looks as the result of other programming languages (aka. Mathematica and Matlab).

For example in Julia

```
using Plots, FFTW, LinearAlgebra
n = 100
Psi = dct(Matrix(1.0I,n,n))
heatmap(Psi)
```

results in this matrix (which is essentially an identity matrix with some noise)

[image: Julia's dct for an identity matrix]

But in Matlab

```
imagesc(dct(eye(100,100),'Type',2))
```

this is the result (as expected)

[image: Matlab dct type 2 of an identity matrix]

Finally in Mathematica

```
MatrixPlot[N[FourierDCTMatrix[100, 2]], PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

returns this

[image: Mathematica dct of an identity matrix]

Why Julia behaves so differently?
And is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab (and I guess Mathematica), does dct of each column in your matrix. FFTW performs a 2-dimensional dct when the input is two-dimensional. The same happens for fft.

If you want column-wise transformation, you can specify the dimension:

```
Psi1 = dct(Matrix(1.0I,n,n), 1);  # along first dimension
heatmap(Psi1)
```

Notice that the direction of the y-axis is opposite for Plots.jl relative to Matlab.

(BTW, you can also just write `I(n)` or `1.0I(n)` instead of `Matrix(1.0I,n,n)`)

[image]

This is something that sets Julia apart from some other languages. It tends to treat matrices as matrices, and not as just a collection of vectors or a bunch of scalars. For example `exp(M)` and `log(M)` for matrices not operate elementwise, but will calculate the matrix exponential and matrix logarithm according to their linear algebra definitions.